# How might an "API Level Analyser" tool work?

Tags: java, android

I work on a high-profile app which runs on all versions of Android. Unfortunately for me the last update on Market included an absolutely-last-minute patch <sigh> which introduced a dependency on an API introduced in 2.0. Every 1.x client who upgraded promptly crashed, causing us to (quite reasonably) get slaughtered in market feedback.

Obviously there are procedural issues here... under no circumstances should we have shipped code not tested on all 4 major platform versions... but that's not why I'm here.

It occurs to me that the tools should be a lot more proactive to avoid this problem.

Put simply, during development I would like to be able to see a list of every place I use an API which was introduced at a level above that specified by `android:targetSdkVersion`.

My question is: How would such a tool work? Would it be possible to write something that looks in each android.jar under <sdk-root>/platforms  of each platform (to build some kind of list of function signatures paired with version numbers) and then do some kind of search? I just don't know enough about the guts of Java/Dalvik to get a real handle on solving the problem.

Comment: I know nothing about Android development, but isn't this a dependency management issue?  The reports that Maven or ANT/Ivy produce could mitigate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I am in the middle of writing a decent answer to this question. In a nutshell I am first building a database by chucking the Android SDK .jars through the standard javap tool. This allows me to build a massive list of APIs (functions, constants, etc) paired with the API level they were introduced in.

The second half of the tool runs on your own .apk and runs dexdump to get an annotated disassembly of each .class. It's then childs play (or should be) to cross-reference each function call to it's API level.

I should have this working within a week or so, will bung it online somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Set Eclipse Android plugin to certain SDK version and you should see errors for APIs that do not exist in this SDK version.

Comment: Unfortunately this also gives lots of errors for totally valid things such as use of a new XML attribute (which, unlike a call to a non-existent Java function, will be ignored when run on older platforms).

Comment: Yes, it may give you XML errors, but you can just ignore then and see if there are errors in the /src/ folders. If so check them, fix them, and set SDK back to 2.2 or whatever you use. You just switch to check API compatibility

Comment: The thought occurs that this is a very similar problem to that solved by @Deprecated.

Comment: You get a million errors under /src because the resource compiler has failed (so no R.java). Have been messing about with dexdump and javap and think I can see a way forward for this...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just build on an earlier version of the SDK?